# Flat dictionary to JSON string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dictionary like the below:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _packetData;
```

I try and convert a dictionary to json, I do json2dictionary also which just converts it to a flat dictionary, but this is in reverse, converting from dictionary2json.

```
public string GetJson()
{
    var entries = _packetData.Select(d => string.Format("\"{0}\": [{1}]", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
    return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
}
```

I've noticed that it doesn't wrap strings with double quotes each end, instead it does this.

```
{"test":test123}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use newtonsoft.json library

Comment: Don’t roll your own JSON serializer. Use Newtonsoft’s JSON.NET

Answer (score 1):

There are no quotes in your output, because you haven't included quotes in your format string, just as you have with the key. I have removed your brackets (`[` and `]`), because they indicate an array value in JSON, and your dictionary has string values, so no need for `string.Join()`.

```
var entries = _packetData.Select(d => string.Format("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", d.Key, d.Value));
```

I would also recommend that you use the Newtonsoft's excellent [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library, which you can find on nuget. Using a library instead of rolling your own implementation is more reliable and often more secure, and often means that you don't need to write as much code. In this case, it would be as simple as:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_packetData);
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm

Answer (score -2):

```
var entries = _packetData.Select(d => string.Format("\"{0}\": [\"{1}\"]", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
```

Comment: This puts []'s around it, what does this change?

Comment: _Please_ provide explanation with your answers. This is the third one of yours I'm running across.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if one of the values includes a `"`?